# Jackson Mapper throws Exception on Android, but not in Java SE

Tags: android, jackson

I'm currently working on a Java Json library. I do the HTTP request stuff myself and let Jackson do the JSON serialization.

The library works fine in most cases but in one case it doesn't.

I have pretty default POJO:

```
      public class MyClass extends MyBase {
           @JsonProperty("MY_PROP")
           private string myProp;

           // ... some properties more

           @JsonProperty("DATA")
           private SubClass data;

           // ... getter/setter
      }
```

The sub class is just a class with mostly Integer fields and two double fields. The super class contains some status infos from the server. This way works in 7 other response classes.

The server response looks like

```
      {
         "MY_PROP":12,
         /* and so on*/
         "DATA":{ /* stuff */ }
      }
```

When I use a little helper class which fires when the HTTP response arrives I get following exception on my android phone:

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class my.company.at.MyClassBase]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

But only on my android phone. If I run a Junit-Test on my Computer - which does exactly the same thing I get the deserialized object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause, but if the class does not have default (no-arg) constructor, maybe try adding one? Javac should add one, if no constructors exist, but I am wondering if Android's compiler might produce different kind of class in this case.

Comment: Didn't help. After adding this constructor it threw strange exceptions about not a unrecognized Property named MY_PROP.

Comment: That error would suggest (as name implies) that the class you try to bind to does not define property "MY_PROP". Quick question: are you trying to bind to MyClass.class (which has it) or MyBase.class (which perhaps does not)? If latter, exception makes sense.

Comment: Nope, I bind it against MyClass. I've started reworking the current app so that it uses GSON instead of Jackson. At the moment GSON is 100% faster than Jackson so I think I'll invest my energy in tweaking GSON instead of researching strange Dalvik/SUN JVM differences. But thanks for the pointer anyway.

Comment: Good luck with GSON then! And when you hit issues with it, Jackson will still be there. :-)